# Server environments which absolutely cannot be virtualized?

Tags: asynchronous, virtualization

I recently joined a development team, and noticed in team meetings that the team is always running short on servers and delayed by lengthy procurement process. We take any box we can find, i.e. we just need more *boxes*, not necessarily the fastest ones. At one meeting I asked why then aren't we virtualizing. I was told something about how virtualization was tried before, but it would not work with something like asynchronous connections. Why virtualization wouldn't work with anything "asynchronous" seemed vague to me, but I don't feel it's best to push the question right now (especially since I'm new there). I get the idea of asynchronous network connections and requests, at the application level, but I'm not clear on why virtualization absolutely **cannot** work in some server environments.

That is, I don't mean "not the best solution", but in what situations is virtualization of servers practically *impossible*?

(Some possibly relevant info about the server environment: we mostly run database servers, web servers, do lots of messaging, queuing, and get times of peak network traffic)

Answer (score 0):

Virtualization of real-time systems is just about the only thing I'd put into the 'impossible' category (at least as far as existing virtualization solutions go) but even then there's nothing about the technology itself that makes that impossible - just the implementations.

Real time systems generally need to be very close to the hardware to ensure that everything happens exactly when it needs to. Ensuring that everything operates 'on-time' would be very difficult/impossible in a virtualized environment due to operational inconsistencies. So putting a real-time system in a non-real-time hypervisor is almost certainly going to cause issues.

As far as a server environment goes, things like DPI/SPI firewalls and related systems which require extremely high throughput and must complete their request within a given time frame would probably the best 'real' example.